# Assertion failed CollectionView must implement Ember.Array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm going a bit nuts ... after having successfully implemented a simple test on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksnyde/BTe8J/4/). I decided to use brunch's ember-reloaded template to build the same application locally. It almost works (I think) but I can not get the main template -- activities.hbs -- to happily load. Instead I get this error:

```
Assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. 
You passed <(generated activities controller):ember204>
```

The activities controller it should be referring to is (although the word "generated" makes me wonder if there is some magic taking place):

```
App = require("app");
App.ActivitiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    toggleDetails: function(target) {
      target = "#activity-details-" + target;
      console.log("Pressed " + target);
      if (jQuery(target).is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery( target ).slideDown( "fast" );
      } else {
        jQuery( target ).slideUp( "fast" );
      }
    }

});
```

Does this make any sense? I've seen several other people post about this error but I'm not finding a direct correlation to what I'm experiencing.

BTW, for additional context, here is my initialize script which gives you a view into the various objects I've defined. For brevities sake I'm not including all the source (although each file is VERY short):

```
// Namespace
require ('app'); 

// ===== Router =====
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function() {});
    this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities' }, function() {});
    this.resource('hi', { path: '/hi' }, function() {});

});

// ===== Routes =====
require ('routes/ActivitiesRoute');

// ===== Store =====
require('stores/fixture');

// ===== Models =====
require('models/Activity');

// ===== Views =====
require('views/IndexView');
// require('views/ActivitiesView');

// ===== Controllers ===== 
require ('controllers/ActivitiesController');

// ===== Template Helpers =====
require('helpers/time');

// ===== Templates =====
require ('templates/application');
require ('templates/hi');
require ('templates/activities');
```

Comment: What is in activities.hbs?

Comment: It's a bit long because of the conditional logic included but I've tested it and it works fine in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksnyde/BTe8J/4/

Comment: If the error is in a template, I would look at `Template > Controller > Route > Model` in that order. In this case I suspect the source of the error is in the template or the controller.

Comment: As the error says "generated activities controller" it means it was not able to find the controller created by you and as a results it created it automatically. Might have been because of some typo in naming the controller. And the generated controller is not an array controller thus saying that the collection view needs ember array.

Comment: @guleria that's very useful info and I'm now 99% sure this points directly to the problem. Let me dig into this morning.

Comment: Do any of you know RequireJS well? I am new to it and am wondering if it is contributing to my problem as spelling mistakes appear NOT to be the issue. I converted a `Brunch` template called [brunch-with-ember-reloaded](https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded) to a template I'm calling [brunch-with-ember-sideloaded](https://github.com/ksnyde/brunch-with-ember-sideloaded) where the primary difference is that mine uses JavaScript not CoffeeScript and I'm worried that I didn't translate the RequireJS stuff correctly from CoffeeScript.